# Call diffrent functions on select change JQ

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys i have 3 Jq functions that Im calling on select change but i think that there is more efficient way than this, Do you have any suggestions

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var divList = $(".listWrapper li");

function sortPriceHighLow() {
  var result = divList.sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(b).data("position") - $(a).data("position")
  });
  $(".listWrapper").html(result); 
}

function sortPriceLowHigh() {
  var result = divList.sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).data("position") - $(b).data("position")
  });
  $(".listWrapper").html(result); 
}

function random() {
  var length = $('.listWrapper li').length 
  $('.listWrapper li').each(function() {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * length); 
    $(this).before($(".listWrapper li:eq(" + j + ")")); 
  })
}   
    $('#priceChanger').on('change', function() {
      if ( $('#priceChanger').val() == 'sortPriceHighLow' ) sortPriceHighLow();
      else if ( $('#priceChanger').val() == 'sortPriceLowHigh' ) sortPriceLowHigh();
      else if ( $('#priceChanger').val() == 'random' ) random();
    });
});
```

**html**

```html
<select class="priceSelect" name="priceChanger" id="priceChanger">
    <option  value="sortPriceHighLow">1</option>
    <option  value="sortPriceLowHigh">2</option>
    <option  value="random">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You could use `switch(this.value)`

Comment: Other than that, there's probably not really a better way to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use just one `change` event handler for `#priceChanger`.

Based on the value, determine a `.sort()` callback to use.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#priceChanger').on('change', function() {

    let sortCallback;

    // Determine the sort callback to use based on $(this) value
    switch ($(this).val()) {

      case "sortPriceHighLow":
        sortCallback = (a, b) => $(b).data("position") - $(a).data("position")
        break;

      case "sortPriceLowHigh":
        sortCallback = (a, b) => $(a).data("position") - $(b).data("position")
        break;

      case "random":
        sortCallback = (a, b) => $(a).data("position") - Math.random() * $('.listWrapper li').length
        break;

      default:
        sortCallback = () => console.log("Bad select value! The list was not sorted.")

    }

    // Apply the selected "sort callback"
    $(".listWrapper").html($(".listWrapper li").sort(sortCallback))

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="priceSelect" name="priceChanger" id="priceChanger">
  <option value="sortPriceHighLow">High to low</option>
  <option value="sortPriceLowHigh" selected>Low to High</option>
  <option value="random">Random</option>
  <option value="xyz">Bad choice</option>
</select>

<ul class="listWrapper">
  <li data-position=1>1.00$</li>
  <li data-position=2>2.00$</li>
  <li data-position=3>3.00$</li>
  <li data-position=4>4.00$</li>
  <li data-position=5>5.00$</li>
  <li data-position=6>6.00$</li>
  <li data-position=7>7.00$</li>
  <li data-position=8>8.00$</li>
  <li data-position=9>9.00$</li>
  <li data-position=10>10.00$</li>
</ul>
```

---

**EDIT**

I added a `default` case in the switch... Because a "bad" value in the select would just silently fail the sorting. So, it is useful to debug ;)